# Magento 2: Make changes to default.xml programmatically

Tags: magento2, theme, default.xml

I was wondering if it's possible to make changes to **`default.xml`** programmatically?

Use case is as follows:

- I want a different theme being loaded when a certain mode is activated for example by clicking on a checkbox.
- Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: You want to change the theme?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change theme basic of some condition.

Then, Do the below steps:

- ***A dropdown on which each option will have URL  mode respective theme id*** at its URL.URL will be  like
  `http//www.example.com/{frontenName}/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}/mode/{RespectivethemeCode}`
- Now  at Action, you need to fetch **mode** parameter value and save
  the **mode** value to `a Session Variable`.
- Last at controller dispatch event change theme based on the  mode session
  variable.

Comment: Yeah yeah i got that you should do something like that, but what event should you let the controller dispatch? I Could not find any event which allows you to load a different theme..

Comment: Hold , i am checking